# Java - Do I need a Database?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I would like to start writing a grade tracking application in java.

I would like for the user to be able to enter their grades, save their data, and exit the application.  I would like the user's data to be "remembered" by the application when the user runs it again.

Can someone point me in the right direction on what kind of tools/languages is needed for this kind of data storage?

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, a database might be overkill, especially if your professor hasn't mentioned it. Otherwise, I'd just start googling for SQL and MySQL documentation. Any one answer here will never give you the depth you need.

Comment: A database would be wise, but in a pinch, a text file, xml file, or other method of persisting the data would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for that you'll need a database. There's much to learn. Take a good look at something like [mySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) or [SQLServer](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/default.aspx). mySQL is free.

You'll also need to learn some [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), which is the language used to communicate with the database. Each database has it's own version of SQL, so check the reference for the database you choose.